# Diferença entre GCC CLang

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Os sistemas baseados em *Unix* (uma grande maioria), normalmente usam o *GCC*, para compilar os arquivos em *C*, mas também possuí o *CLang* para a mesma finalidade.

> Existe diferença na hora de compilar algum projeto usando *GCC* e *CLang*?

Comment: O CLang foi projetado para ser capaz de substituir o GCC. É um projeto de código fonte aberto com grandes contribuidores, tais como Apple, Microsoft, Google, ARM, Sony, Intel and Advanced Micro Devices (AMD). Site com uma comparação entre GCC e CLang: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ClangDiagnosticsComparison

Comment: Eu gosto de usar o `-Weverything` com clang. Mesmo `-Wall -Wextra` com gcc ainda deixa alguns warnings desabilitados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra responder sua pergunta temos de fazer uma breve reflexão.

1. -O [CLang](http://clang.llvm.org/) trata apenas do **front-end** , "digamos que ele lida basicamente com as opções e os caminhos de linkedições para os arquivos", para a compilação em si, ele utiliza o [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) que é o responsável pela análise léxica, sintática e semântica do processo de compilação. O [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) é um conjunto completo com **front-end** e **back-end**.
2. O [Sumário de opções de Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options) embora possua muitas opções básicas iguais, também contém opções de compilação diferentes do [Sumário de opções do GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary).
3. O GCC além C, C++, Objective-C, possui **front-end** para outras linguagens como , [Fortran, Java, Ada, e mais recentemente Go], os nomes podem mudar como o g++ e GFortran mas ainda coninuam sendo parte do projeto GCC. Já o Clang possui front-end apenas para linguagens baseadas em C [C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++].
4. Como LLVM e GCC são compiladores diferentes, possuem implementações diferentes, portanto a ordem do conjunto básicos de instruções gerado é diferente.
   Isso afeta tanto o tempo de compilação, uma vez que possuem implementações diferentes, quanto tempo de execução de um programa, uma vez que passam por passos de otimização diferentes e gerem instruções básicas diferentes.

> Bom dito isso, espero que tenha ficado claro que embora os comandos básicos
>   sejam iguais, compilar um programa usando GCC é diferente de compilar
>   um programa usando Clang + LLVM.

Comment: Apenas para complementar a responsa do Gabriel, embora o código do programa final seja diferente, o resultado da execução do programa em ambos os compiladores é esperado que seja o mesmo uma vez que estão compilando o mesmo programa na mesma linguagem.

Comment: O primeiro ponto está de todas as formas incorreto. O Clang é um front-end para as famílias de linguagem C (C, C++, Objective-C etc), que cuida da análise léxica, sintática e semântica e gera uma IR não otimizada. O LLVM é um back-end que otimiza e converte IR para alguma ISA de uma arquitetura alvo.